# Genre of KNW THT by YUKI AME

Tags: identify-this-genre, soul

I'm looking for music like this, that I would be able to use in a mobile app ad (the author won't let me use theirs):

https://soundcloud.com/yukinoame/knw-tht

I know it's sampled from Lakeside — Given in to Love. The original is some kind of soul — but what genre is this uplifting funky chopped version at the link? I tried searching for soul, funk, beats, lo-fi beats, but that's not it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I let your link play, Soundcloud automatically went on to another song in the same style, "Maybe" by Letherette.  That gives hope it's actually a subgenre and not a one-off.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Great idea actually, to simply follow the trail of similar tracks! Seems like they call it Future Funk.

Comment: Good find, I expanded this into a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subgenre of a subgenre of a subgenre!  The larger subgenre is called [Vaporwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporwave) and here's what has been said about it:

> Vaporwave is a microgenre of electronic music and an Internet meme that emerged in the early 2010s.[16] The style is defined by its appropriation of 1980s and 1990s mood music styles such as smooth jazz, elevator music, R&B, and lounge music, typically sampling or manipulating tracks via chopped and screwed techniques and other effects.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporwave
>
> Starting as arguably the first internet-born music genre in 2010, Vaporwave attempted something that had never really been done in the realm of music: to create a nostalgia for something that never truly existed. With a focus on 80’s and 90’s consumerism and yuppie culture, cult electronic artists Daniel Lopatin (known as “Chuck Person” within Vaporwave) and James Ferraro created a new sound in music by creating songs reminiscent of old ringtones and manipulating old samples of songs long forgotten.
>
> https://medium.com/@Thorcb/vaporwave-revisited-a-second-look-at-the-forever-mutating-genre-b7da26d76ca3

In more recent years, Vaporwave mutated into a more funky and danceable version based on heavily remixed old funk records called "Future Funk."

- [Saint Pepsi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r2zleGxv7w)
- [Maybe - Letherette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8Pz6bAGWFg)

Your song is basically a subtype of this, but focused on more of a smoother, soul-based sound.  There's no real name for it, but I had some success finding examples described as "Soul Vaporwave":

- [Flamingosis - "think back and remember"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kW3dbCcnxnE)
- [Neither One of Us - Sweeps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0qfBtSatGY)

Comment: Not sure if it's correct to label it as vaporwave — to me it seems like 'vaporwave' is just another mistakenly overused term like EDM for example (a lot of people just label any electronic music from minimal to big room trance as EDM). Otherwise great answer!

Comment: @Actine Thanks for introducing me to this enjoyable style! :)  I agree this is quite different from where Vaporwave started, but if you follow the trail of influences, it looks like this is how people got there.